# does Typescript address global package for module resolution in compiling

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

by NPM tool I install `@types/bluebird-global` package on my machine.. when I install it as local package, it does work.. typescript can find it and compile sourcecode without any problem. but if I add switch "-g" in NPM command and install it as global, VS can not find it. I am a beginner for typescript. If i did wrong, please give me some instructions. if no wrong in my practices, I will post it as required feature to typescript team. 
thanks.

Comment: Have you read the [Module Resolution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html) part of the docs?

Comment: have been quick through that part...and it seems almost relative path address...  unless one.... "baseUrl" in compilerOptions, I just wondered my direction is correct or not... and suspect that's wrong way..

Comment: Do not use global modules

Answer (score -1, accepted):

get [feedback](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13659#event-935132089) from ms typescript team: global package is only for CML application.